# Convert NSData from local NSURL

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdata, nsurl

I have a sound player which uses AVAudioPlayer class. I download some items in another view and store the filepath to it as NSURL, then pass the NSURL to the Player viewcontroller. But i get an error while trying to pass the object.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString path]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1700c86c0'
```

And here is the code:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[podcastSource path]];
NSError *error;
mPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:&error];
[mPlayer setDelegate:self];

if (mPlayer == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}
else
{
    [self.player play];
....
}
```

Note that the filePath i receive from the NSURL is in this form:

```
/var/mobile/Applications/xxxxxx/Documents/90989.mp3
```

Comment: From the error it seems as if podcastSource is a string when it should be an url... Convert it to an NSUrl before requesting its path.

Comment: It seems "podcastSource" is string and you are using it as `NSURL` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error it seems as if `podcastSource` is an NSString when it needs to be an `NSUrl` if you're going to request its path.

But [according to the Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfFile%3a), `dataWithContentsOfFile:` accepts an NSString as the argument, so no need to convert `podcastSource` into an `NSUrl` or to request that `NSUrl`'s path.

If `podcastSource` is your filename in its entirety, this should work:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:podcastSource];
```